# Decrease in Google+ followers

Tags: google-plus, followers

I'm not getting this. From last week, whenever I sign in my Google+ account I find a decreased number of followers. In fact, they didn't unfollow me. Is it really a bug or is it just me suffering with it?

How can I stop it?

Comment: How do you know that people did not unFollow you?